# How to send smtps message to standalone greenmail server

Tags: mule, greenmail, smtps

I have a mule flow that needs to send a smtps message to a greenmail server.

The mule flow uses the smtps connector with configure keystore and truststore:

`<smtps:connector name="SMTPS_Connector" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SMTP">
        <smtps:tls-client path="${keystore.path}" storePassword="${keystore.password}"/>
        <smtps:tls-trust-store path="${truststore.path}" storePassword="${truststore.password}"/>
    </smtps:connector>`

My greenmail server is started using default values.

When I invoke my flow to send an email I get the following logs:

In the Mule Log:

> ERROR 2017-03-17 19:33:38,106 [Default_HTTP_Connector.receiver.06]
>   org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
>   ******************************************************************************** Message               : Unable to connect to mail transport. Code
>   : MULE_ERROR--2
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception stack is:
>   1. No trusted certificate found (sun.security.validator.ValidatorException)
>   sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator:396 (null)
>   2. sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException)
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts:192
>   (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLHandshakeException.html)
>   3. Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 3465 (javax.mail.MessagingException)   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport:1706
>   (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/mail/MessagingException.html)
>   4. Unable to connect to mail transport. (org.mule.api.endpoint.EndpointException)
>   org.mule.transport.email.SmtpMessageDispatcher:67
>   (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/endpoint/EndpointException.html)
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Root Exception stack trace: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
>   No trusted certificate found  at
>   sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.buildTrustedChain(SimpleValidator.java:396)
>     at
>   sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator.engineValidate(SimpleValidator.java:134)
>     at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
>       + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
>
> ---

In the Greenmail Server log:

> ERROR 2017-03-17 19:33:38,086 [smtps:localhost:3465<-/127.0.0.1:27671]
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.smtp.SmtpHandler: Unexpected error handling
>   connection, quitting= javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been
>   shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
>   certificate_unknown   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1508)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:92)  at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)     at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)     at
>   java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)    at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)  at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)  at
>   java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)  at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.smtp.SmtpConnection.receiveLine(SmtpConnection.java:57)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.smtp.SmtpHandler.handleCommand(SmtpHandler.java:82)
>     at com.icegreen.greenmail.smtp.SmtpHandler.run(SmtpHandler.java:56)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.server.AbstractServer$1.run(AbstractServer.java:163)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert:
>   certificate_unknown   at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1991)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1098)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:721)
>     at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
>     at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)  at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)  at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)    at
>   java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)     at
>   java.io.PrintWriter.flush(PrintWriter.java:320)   at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.util.InternetPrintWriter.println(InternetPrintWriter.java:91)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.util.InternetPrintWriter.println(InternetPrintWriter.java:196)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.smtp.SmtpConnection.send(SmtpConnection.java:48)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.smtp.SmtpHandler.sendGreetings(SmtpHandler.java:76)
>     at com.icegreen.greenmail.smtp.SmtpHandler.run(SmtpHandler.java:53)
>     ... 2 more

Is seems that I need to specify a keystore on my Greenmail server but I can't find a way to do it.

I tried placing a greenmail.jks with password 'changeit' in the classpath but it is giving me this error on start up:

> ERROR 2017-03-17 17:42:24,185 [smtps:localhost:3465]
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.util.DummySSLServerSocketFactory: Can not
>   create and initialize SSL java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException:
>   Cannot recover key    at
>   sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:328)     at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:138)
>     at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
>     at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:804)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:68)
>     at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:259)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.util.DummySSLServerSocketFactory.(DummySSLServerSocketFactory.java:56)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.util.DummySSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault(DummySSLServerSocketFactory.java:87)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.server.AbstractServer.openServerSocket(AbstractServer.java:63)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.server.AbstractServer.initServerSocket(AbstractServer.java:115)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.server.AbstractServer.run(AbstractServer.java:86)
>   Exception in thread "smtps:localhost:3465"
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not create and initialize SSL    at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.util.DummySSLServerSocketFactory.(DummySSLServerSocketFactory.java:65)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.util.DummySSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault(DummySSLServerSocketFactory.java:87)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.server.AbstractServer.openServerSocket(AbstractServer.java:63)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.server.AbstractServer.initServerSocket(AbstractServer.java:115)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.server.AbstractServer.run(AbstractServer.java:86)
>   Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
>     at sun.security.provider.KeyProtector.recover(KeyProtector.java:328)
>     at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:138)
>     at
>   sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
>     at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:804)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:131)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:68)
>     at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:259)
>     at
>   com.icegreen.greenmail.util.DummySSLServerSocketFactory.(DummySSLServerSocketFactory.java:56)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I had to change all the passwords (keystore, keys) to greenmail's default password.  Currently, I am unable to change the socket factory being used so I could not change the greenmail password since it is hardcoded in the socket factory.

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the greenmail.jks ? If you are using "keytool -genkey ...."  notice that you will 2 passwords.

The first refering to the .jks file and the second one refering to the key password. IF you are setting up the server with this jks, you will have to set both the "Key Password" and "Password", otherwise you will receive the error :

sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:138) at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineGetKey(JavaKeyStore.java:55) at

Example of keytool command:

> keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore greenmailServer.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 2048

Follow the steps and notice that you will be asked for the "Key Password".

Unfortunately, I can't help you in setting the smtp server and I guess this is not the replace for that.

Regards!

Comment: Hi Mario. Yes I used keytool.  What I did was to set the password for the store and cert to 'changeit'.  If your familiar with the greenmail DummySSLServerSocketFactory and if you look at the source you can see that the password is hardcoded to the value 'changeit'.  Not to familiar with how socket factories work, so I'm still looking at how the keystore and cert passwords are used/set.